# Error Read CSV file java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, csvreader

in my spring boot application I have created a REST API POST method that read a file csv in a folder and than save on db in this way:

```
@Override
public ResponseList updateDataFromCSV(CsvDataInputBean csvDataInputBean)
        throws IllegalStateException, FileNotFoundException {
    final String methodName = String.format("updateDataFromCSV %s", csvDataInputBean);
    try {
        startLog(methodName, csvDataInputBean);
        ResponseList response = new ResponseList();
        log.info("Input path " + csvDataInputBean.getPath().toString());
        List<CsvUserPojo> csvUserFile = new CsvToBeanBuilder<CsvUserPojo>(
                new FileReader(csvDataInputBean.getPath())).withType(CsvUserPojo.class).withSeparator(';').build()
                        .parse();
        List<UserEntity> listToSave = new LinkedList<>();
        List<UserModel> listOfModels = new LinkedList<>();
        for (CsvUserPojo csvUser : csvUserFile) {
            log.info("User present in CSV file: " + csvUser);
            UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
            Optional<UserEntity> userByCF = userRepository.findByCf(csvUser.getCf().toUpperCase());

        if (!userByCF.isPresent()) {
            userEntity.setName(Arrays.stream(csvUser.getName().split(" "))
                    .map(word -> word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1).toLowerCase())
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));

            userEntity.setSurname(Arrays.stream(csvUser.getSurname().split(" "))
                    .map(word -> word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1).toLowerCase())
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));

            userEntity.setGender(StringUtils.capitalize(csvUser.getGender()));

            userEntity.setAge(csvUser.getAge());

            userEntity.setCf(csvUser.getCf().toUpperCase());

            userEntity.setAddress(Arrays.stream(csvUser.getAddress().split(" "))
                    .map(word -> word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1).toLowerCase())
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));

            userEntity.setMail(csvUser.getMail());

            listToSave.add(userEntity);

            UserModel userModel = ConvertersUtils.createUserModelFromUserEntity(userEntity);
            listOfModels.add(userModel);

            log.info("User saved on DB: " + userEntity.getCf().toUpperCase());
        } else {
            log.info("User with CF: " + userByCF.get().getCf().toUpperCase() + " already present on DB");
        }
    }
    if (listToSave.isEmpty()) {
        endLog(methodName, listToSave, LogConstant.LOG_GENERIC_ERROR);
        response.setMessage(LogConstant.LOG_GENERIC_ERROR + " No new Users have been added");
        response.setTotalResult(listOfModels.size());
        response.setUsers(listOfModels);
        return response;
    } else {
        userRepository.saveAll(listToSave);
        endLog(methodName, listToSave, LogConstant.LOG_SUCCESS);
        response.setMessage(LogConstant.LOG_SUCCESS + " " + listToSave.size() + " Users have been added");
        response.setTotalResult(listOfModels.size());
        response.setUsers(listOfModels);
        return response;
    }
} catch (final Exception e) {
    this.errorLog(methodName, e);
    throw e;
}
```

}

If I try to use it in local I have no problem and STS read the file csv on the folder .../Downloads/User.csv.

I have also created a file docker-compose.yml like this:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  #new service (java_app)
  java_app:
    container_name: java_app
    image: java_app:1.0.0
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8000:8080
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://java_db:5432/testuserdb
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=postgres
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=postgres
    depends_on:
      - java_db

  #old service (postgres)
  java_db:
    container_name: java_db
    image: postgres:12
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: testuserdb
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  pgdata: {}
```

When I try to execute the POST API REST, with the same path, in the log of docker desktop I see:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\PastoreGu\Downloads\User1.csv (No such file or directory)
```

How can I solve it?